# javascript regex for password containing at least 8 characters, 1 number, 1 upper and 1 lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am trying to write a regular expression to validate a password which must meet the following criteria:

- Contain at least 8 characters
- contain at least 1 number
- contain at least 1 lowercase character (a-z)
- contain at least 1 uppercase character (A-Z)
- contains only 0-9a-zA-Z

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/many_tentacles/Hzuc9/

```
<input type='button' value='click' class='buttonClick' />
<input type='text' />
<div></div>
```

and...

```
$(".buttonClick").click(function () {

    if ($("input[type=text]").filter(function () {
        return this.value.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/);
    })) {
        $("div").text("pass");
    } else {
        $("div").text("fail");
    }

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `contains only 0-9a-zA-Z` is a really bad rule

Comment: solution refer:  https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/103764/Password-validation-using-regular-expression-in-jQuery/

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Your regular expression should look like:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/
```

Here is an explanation:

```
/^
  (?=.*\d)          // should contain at least one digit
  (?=.*[a-z])       // should contain at least one lower case
  (?=.*[A-Z])       // should contain at least one upper case
  [a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}   // should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters
$/
```

Comment: This is not doing what the OP (mistakenly, in my opinion) is asking for. It allows other characters than alphanumerics.

Comment: Works like a charm! http://www.rubular.com/r/jf69EWPQ4N

Comment: (/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/) if the user can enter symbols and spaces - allows for a more secure password

Comment: this will work with html5 form validation right?

Comment: no validate one letter in Uppercase

Comment: I think I am late... But, I don't think it will work when I want to set password with other characters.It will work in _abcItisPass43_ but not in _abcItisPass43&_ . What I am saying is, doesn't work in characters like _$, %, &, #_ and so on.

Comment: testing it with fjd3IR9@*^#!#%^@%# will return to true.

Answer (score 23):

Using individual regular expressions to test the different parts would be considerably easier than trying to get one single regular expression to cover all of them. It also makes it easier to add or remove validation criteria.

Note, also, that your usage of `.filter()` was incorrect; it will always return a jQuery object (which is considered truthy in JavaScript). Personally, I'd use an `.each()` loop to iterate over all of the inputs, and report individual pass/fail statuses. Something like the below:

```
$(".buttonClick").click(function () {

    $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
        var validated =  true;
        if(this.value.length < 8)
            validated = false;
        if(!/\d/.test(this.value))
            validated = false;
        if(!/[a-z]/.test(this.value))
            validated = false;
        if(!/[A-Z]/.test(this.value))
            validated = false;
        if(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(this.value))
            validated = false;
        $('div').text(validated ? "pass" : "fail");
        // use DOM traversal to select the correct div for this input above
    });
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/ozovod/1)

Comment: It seems you forgot '!'
        if(!/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(this.value))

Comment: @hodcaspi It's a five and a half year old answer, but no, I definitely didn't.

Answer (score 10):

At least 8 = `{8,}`:

```
str.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex only allows exactly 8 characters. Use `{8,}` to specify eight or more instead of `{8}`.

But why would you limit the allowed character range for your passwords? 8-character alphanumeric passwords can be bruteforced by my *phone*  within minutes.