# jQuery Validation - password MUST contain uppercase and number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So in my registration form I have this field:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="RegisterModel_Password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="RegisterModel_Password" 
           name="RegisterModel.Password" class="form-control" 
           required="required" minlength="8"/>
</div>
```

As you see, I'm using jQuery validation attributes to ensure that the password includes at least 8 characters. So, I want to check if password contains uppercase and number, if not, field is not valid. I downloaded additional method for jQuery Validation plugin named "[pattern](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/pattern.js)" and added her in head tag.

I tried to do this as follows but it didn't worked.

```
$("#formRegister").validate({
    rules: {
        RegisterModel_Password: {
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z][0-9]/
        }
    }
});
```

I assume that the pattern is wrong, but I'm not sure whether the use is correct.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here, some pattern documentation bro: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/  Hope it helped! ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850553/javascript-regex-for-password-containing-at-least-8-characters-1-number-1-uppe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password REGEX with min 6 chars, at least one letter and one number and may contain special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844359/password-regex-with-min-6-chars-at-least-one-letter-and-one-number-and-may-cont)

Comment: Please don't enforce such a rule. Normally I generate passwords with `head -c 18 /dev/urandom | base64` and sometimes there is no digit, or no upper case character in the result. That's just a property of randomness that you can't exactly tell how the output looks like. Nevertheless the the password strength is 18 bytes. You may assume that your users are not stupid.

Comment: @Kay *" You may assume that your users are not stupid. "* hahaha....hahahaha... oh boy!  good one :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chains of regular expressions are too hard for me ( I have never tried to learn them lol ). So here is my solution:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("passwordCheck",
        function(value, element, param) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            } else if (!/[A-Z]/.test(value)) {
                return false;
            } else if (!/[a-z]/.test(value)) {
                return false;
            } else if (!/[0-9]/.test(value)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        },
        "error msg here");
```

And simply I use it like a attribute:

```
<input type="password" id="RegisterModel_Password" 
name="RegisterModel.Password" 
class="form-control" 
required="required" minlength="8" 
passwordCheck="passwordCheck"/>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than using regex. I would still add a `value.length >= 8` test for completeness, if the browser does not enforce the `minlength` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom validation using `$.validator.addMethod()` like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validation_name", function(value) {
    // at least 1 number and at least 1 character
    [^\w\d]*(([0-9]+.*[A-Za-z]+.*)|[A-Za-z]+.*([0-9]+.*))
});
```