# How to validate password using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I Tried to validate a statement with below regular expression, In some of the cases it is working as expected but not in the other cases.

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{12,20}$/
```

passed scenario's

```
test@Test123
```

Failed Scenario's

```
test.Test123
```

In this scenario we can allow alphanumeric,at least one special character and length should be in between    to 20 characters.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking any more questions. Unless you ask a question that can be answered you cannot expect to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service.With a little bit of research you should be able to get most of this, if not all figured out and when you have actual code that isn't working ask questions

Comment: I forgot to include, Now I added in the question

Comment: Read `How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` at the link I gave you. Provide a MCVE if you want meaningful help.

Comment: Just add the `.<>` character inside the character class `[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&.<>]`

Comment: I tried `[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&.<>]` this, But it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex for password containing at least 8 characters, 1 number, 1 upper and 1 lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850553/javascript-regex-for-password-containing-at-least-8-characters-1-number-1-uppe)

Comment: Also, don't do this client-side. It's a bad idea. Also, don't limit the password to specific characters, you're making your system **extremely vulnerable** the way you're coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Though,the question was duplicate.

Answer for your question:
This pattern will help you to validate:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{8,}$/
```

At least 
--one upper case English letter
--one lower case English letter
--one digit
--one special character
--Minimum eight in length

Comment: It should be alphanumeric, at least one special character and length should be 12-20 characters. There is no upper case letter in this

Comment: The below may resolve the issue. `/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{12,20}$/`